# How to get the id of the sorted item of the spinner?

Tags: android, json, sorting, spinner

I am getting data from the json. I have sorted the country name accordingly alphabetically.but when i click on the spinner item i am getting the worng id of the item.can anyone tell me how can i get the id of the sorted item of the spinner.

This is my json:-

```
{
  "Status": 1,
  "StatusMessage": "Country and Country Area List",
  "data": [
    {
      "CountryID": "1",
      "CountryName": "India",
      "CountryArea": [
        {
          "CountryID": "1",
          "AreaID": "1",
          "AreaName": "Kuwait City(Capital)"
        },
        {
          "CountryID": "1",
          "AreaID": "2",
          "AreaName": " Hawally"
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      "CountryID": "2",
      "CountryName": "Dubai",
      "CountryArea": [
        {
          "CountryID": "2",
          "AreaID": "6",
          "AreaName": " Jeddah"
        },
        {
          "CountryID": "2",
          "AreaID": "7",
          "AreaName": " Riyadh"
```

This is the method by which i am getting data from the json :-

```
 public void requestDataCountry() {

            mProgressDialog.show();
            StringRequest countrylistrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GlobalData.COUNTRYLISTURL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {

                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                if (jObject.getString("Status").equals("1")) {


                                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        mCountryName = jsonObject.getString("CountryName");
                                        mId = jsonObject.getString("CountryID");
                                        mCountryList.add(mCountryName);
                                        Collections.sort(mCountryList);
                                        getCountryId.add(mId);





                                        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("CountryArea");
                                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {

                                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                            String countryAreaId = jsonObject1.getString("CountryID");


                                            mAreaName = jsonObject1.getString("AreaName");
                                            mAreaList.add(mAreaName);




                                        }
                                    }





                                    countryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                                } else {

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {




                        }
                    }) {


            };

            RequestQueue countryqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

            countryqueue.add(countrylistrequest);

        }
```

This is my Spinner Code :-

```
   @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner).setVisible(true);
        mCountrySpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);


        countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mCountryList);
        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

        mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                mCountrySerachId = getCountryId.get(position);


                mEditor.putString(KEY_COUNTRY_ID, mCountrySerachId);
                mEditor.commit();



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
```

My problem is when i click on the spinner item like i click on Dubai(CountryName)as per my json then i am getting the id 1(CountryID).while i click on the Dubai(CountryName) it should get the id 2(CountryID). i knew the problem i sorted the CountryName but i did not sort the CountryID.then my question is how can i sort the CountryID according to the CountryName.

Answer (score 0):

Save your parsed values(ID and Country name) in a Hashmap. Then sort the hashmap using the code below.

```
public LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> sortHashMapByValues(
        HashMap<Integer, String> passedMap) {
    List<Integer> mapKeys = new ArrayList<>(passedMap.keySet());
    List<String> mapValues = new ArrayList<>(passedMap.values());
    Collections.sort(mapValues);
    Collections.sort(mapKeys);

    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> sortedMap =
        new LinkedHashMap<>();

    Iterator<String> valueIt = mapValues.iterator();
    while (valueIt.hasNext()) {
        String val = valueIt.next();
        Iterator<Integer> keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

        while (keyIt.hasNext()) {
            Integer key = keyIt.next();
            String comp1 = passedMap.get(key);
            String comp2 = val;

            if (comp1.equals(comp2)) {
                keyIt.remove();
                sortedMap.put(key, val);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Comment: @ Febi Mathew Dear sir,your method is absolutely right. but i want to sort the list alphabetically.your method giving me the same id but it did not sort the Country name alphabetically. so please tell me how can i sort the Country name alphabetically and after that it gives the same country id.